# What is the status of the Stellar Open Institute? Can developers still get involved?

Tags: developersguide, new-developer

I know there is a new roadmap coming out on January 25th, but I am curious about a small section of the roadmap Jed posted back in 2016.

In that document, there is a section about the Stellar Open Institute slated for 2017 and in the Impact section there is a stated goal of having 1,000 developers trained.

Has anyone enrolled in Stellar Open Institute? Is it possible to still enroll? And if anyone in this community has participated in the program, can you tell us about your experience?

Comment: do you have a link or source for this?

Comment: https://www.stellar.org/blog/roadmap/

Comment: If you look at the bottom of that blog post there is a table where they talk about the institute and the targeted number of trained developers

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no active plans with the Stellar Open Institute. Instead, we have other initiatives in the works.

To stay updated on what's coming, I recommend you sign up for the [Stellar developer mailing list](http://stellar.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=c001d97369b7a10d224c23867&id=e1f435dc0a).